# Authentication date and time

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, authentication, datetime

How do I save the date and time of user's authentication in an MVC .net web application? I have to save it in order to modify the database I'm using in my application.

Comment: Add `DateTime` field into that table and update this field when user credential are correct.

Comment: BTW, it's "Authentication", not "Authentification".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It really depends on how your database model is structured. Assuming a User table:

```
User
-------
ID UserName Password
```

Add a new column `LastLoggedInDate` like so:

```
User (with logged in date)
-------
ID UserName Password LastLoggedInDate
```

Alternately, if you have a need to see log in history, consider a second table to log logins:

```
LoginAttempt
------------
ID UserID DateStamp Successful
```

This `LoginAttempt` table can be extended further to include an authentication code with an expiry date for use in integrated authentication (not to be mistaken Windows Integrated Security), or distributed authentication (API).

```
LoginAttempt (with auth code)
------------
ID UserID DateStamp Successful AuthCode ExpirationDate
```